# Android home screen widget, create from activity

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen

I am trying to craete my first home screen widget.
I create it and adjust, and all is ok.
But I can't find there is a way to create widget from activity.
For example I have a button on my main activity. 
User hasn't created widget on his screen.
Can I create programmatically widget? For example by button click listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Pinning App Widgets documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#Pinning), on API 26+ devices, allows your app to launch the widget interface to pin a specific widget by using the [requestPinAppWidget()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) API. Apps must use [isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) to check to make sure the launcher supports this functionality.

There's no equivalent on earlier versions of Android.